# Is this a correct UML activity diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

Made this diagram for my tictactoe game.
It is an activity diagram
here is a link:
http://i58.tinypic.com/fo26n4.png
tell me if it is correct. Thanks

- Is it correct?
- What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No. The problems are:

- you haven't created the loop for each move.
- Put there a switch X-O for every turn
- Tie a player to X and to O.
- `Check winner` sounds strange. Look for three in line would be better.
- Add `declare current player as a winner`.

Comment: hmm change "check winner" to "exchange turns" then "look at results" then a diamond if you win/lose/tie? if you win add score if lose or tie no score.

Comment: @spoderman69 I would change "check winner" to "switch current player". (I am leaving to mountains in an hour for a week, so don't expect immediate reaction)

Comment: ohhh ok. hmm bummer. thanks for the help. can u help me with my other diagrams? i need 4-5 diagrams of this tictactoe game. just tell me whats wrong with my diagrams. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @spoderman69 hi. You can put your diagrams, with explanation what they should model, as questions.

Comment: hello. I need your opinions with my other diagrams. take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592455/are-my-uml-diagrams-correct/22592818?noredirect=1#comment34469169_22592818